# XPath/XSLT: how to select all elements that satisfy a condition involving another set of elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document similar to the following:

```
<tt>
  <a text="1"/>
  <a text="2"/>
  ...
  <a text="n"/>

  <b text="14">data</b>
  <b text="2">data</b>
  ...
</tt>
```

How can I select all `<b>` elements that have `text` attribute not equal to the `text` attribute of any of the `<a>` elements? I'm using XPath 1.0.

I've thinking about something like `tt/b[not (tt/a[@text = xxx::@text])]`, where `xxx` should refer to the `tt/b` element being examined. I don't know how exactly it may be done.

Comment: The important bit for me was that `not(tt/a[@text = xxx::@text])` can be written as `not(@text = tt/a/@text`. But anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**An answer such as `/tt/b[@text != ../a/@text]` is wrong and selects the wrong set of nodes**:

```
<b text="14">data</b>
<b text="2">data</b>
```

As we see, the second selected node's `text` attribute is `2` and there *is* an `a` element whose `text` attribute is `2`.

**Here is a correct XPath expression**:

```
/tt/b[not(@text = ../a/@text)]
```

**When evaluated against the provided XML document**:

```
<tt>
  <a text="1"/>
  <a text="2"/>
  ...
  <a text="n"/>

  <b text="14">data</b>
  <b text="2">data</b>
  ...
</tt>
```

**it correctly selects only one node**:

```
<b text="14">data</b>
```

**Explanation**:

By definition **[the XPath `!=` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)** has a very unintuitive behavior whenever at least one of its arguments is a node-set:

**From the [W3C XPath 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)**:

> "If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a number,
>   then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   number to be compared and on the result of converting the string-value
>   of that node to a number using the number function is true. If one
>   object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then
>   the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true"

In this particular case for the element:

```
<b text="2">data</b>
```

The comparison:

```
@text != ../a/@text
```

is `true()` even though there exists:

```
<a text="2"/>
```

because there exist at least one `../a` element (and actually more than one), the string (or numeric) value of whose `text` attribute isn't equal to `"2"`.

**This is a well-known fact and a FAQ**: Always avoid using the `!=` operator unless you absolutely know what you are doing!

**The correct solution of this problem is to use the `not()` function like this**:

```
not(@text = ../a/@text)
```

This expression evaluates to `true()` only if `@text = ../a/@text` is `false()` -- that is only if there isn't even a single `../a/@text` whose string value is equal to the string value of the `text` attribute of the context node.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/tt/b[not(@text = ../a/@text)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the correct result is produced**:

```
<b text="14">data</b>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't delete an accepted answer. I see the problem. +1

Comment: @empo: Thanks. Things like this sometimes happen at SO. The important and good thing is that *everyone* learns a lot from such happenings. Your answer is no longer accepted -- please decide what to do with it.

Comment: @empo: OK, I updated my answer not to mention a no-longer existing wrong answer.